# Calculator Command responding with errors | Discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js

I recently made a **calculator** command but I have been getting issues with it. I am using Discord.js v13, I have a feeling the issue is with the new interaction - buttons but not sure. I could not find any other help in the docs or anywhere with this issue so hoping someone here could help me with this.

**Error:**

```
let collect = createCollector(filter, { time: time });
                                  ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at createCollector (calculator.js:42:39)
    at createCollector (calculator.js:42:39)
    at createCollector (calculator.js:42:39)
    at createCollector (calculator.js:42:39)
    at createCollector (calculator.js:42:39)
    at createCollector (calculator.js:42:39)
    at createCollector (calculator.js:42:39)
    at createCollector (calculator.js:42:39)
    at createCollector (calculator.js:42:39)
    at createCollector (calculator.js:42:39)
```

**Packages:**

```
const { MessageEmbed, MessageButton, MessageActionRow } = require('discord.js');
const math = require('math');
```

**Command:**

````
let button = new Array([], [], [], [], []);
let row = [];
let text = ["clear", "(", ")", "/", "7", "8", "9", "*", "4", "5", "6", "-", "1", "2", "3", "+", ".", "0", "00", "="];
let current = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (button[current].length === 4) current++;
  button[current].push(createButton(text[i]));
  if (i === text.length - 1) {
    for (let btn of button) row.push(addRow(btn));
  };
};

const calculator = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(':plus: Calculator!')
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  .setDescription('```0```');

message.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: row }).then((msg) => {
  let isWrong = false;
  let time = 60000; // 60000 = 1m | 12000 = 2m | 18000 = 3m | 24000 = 4m | 30000 = 5m
  let value = '';
  let embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(':plus: Calculator!')
    .setColor('BLUE');

  function createCollector(val, result = false) {
    let filter = (buttons1) => buttons1.clicker.user.id === message.author.id && buttons1.id === 'calc' + val;
    let collect = createCollector(filter, { time: time });

    collect.on('collect', async x => {
      x.defer();

      if (result === 'new') value = '0';
      else if (isWrong) {
        value = val;
        isWrong = false;
      }
      else if (value === '0') value = val;
      else if (result) {
        isWrong = true;
        value = mathEval(value);
      }
      else value += val;

      embed1.setDescription(`\`\`\`${value}\`\`\``)
      msg.edit({ embeds: [embed1], components: row })
    });
  };

  for (let txt of text) {
    let result;
    if (txt === 'clear') result = 'new';
    else if (txt === '=') result = true;
    else result = false;
    createCollector(txt, result);
  };

  setTimeout(() => {
    embed1.setDescription('You ran out of time! Restart the command.');
    embed1.setColor('RED');
    msg.edit({ embeds: [embed1] });
  }, time)
})

function addRow(btns) {
  let row1 = new MessageActionRow();
  for (let btn of btns) {
    row1.addComponents(btn);
  };
  return row1;
};

function createButton(label, style = 'SECONDARY') {
  if (label === 'clear') style = 'DANGER';
  else if (label === '.') style = 'SECONDARY';
  else if (label === '=') style = 'SUCCESS';
  else if (isNaN(label)) style = 'PRIMARY';

  const btn = new MessageButton()
    .setLabel(label)
    .setStyle(style)
    .setCustomId('cal' + label);
  return btn;
};

function mathEval(input) {
  try {
    let res = math.evaluate(input);
    return res;
  } catch {
    return 'Wrong input!';
  }
}
````

Comment: You are recursively calling createCollector inside createCollector. This is most likely unintended.

Answer (score 0):

This little piece of code:

```js
  function createCollector(val, result = false) {
    let filter = (buttons1) => buttons1.clicker.user.id === message.author.id && buttons1.id === 'calc' + val;
    let collect = createCollector(filter, { time: time });
```

in `let collect = createCollector` you're calling `createCollector` again, in which it will call `createCollector` and make an infinite loop.

NodeJS detects this infinite loop, and so throws an error.